# data cleansing javascript objects

Tags: javascript, regex, json, performance, node.js

I have a http server built in node.js and 'connect'.  The web service currently parses JSON requests to an Object, does "stuff", and returns a synchronous response.  The JSON is from an ecommerce cart and I end up with an Object that looks like (abridged version):

```
var myObj = {"request":{"industry":"social","transactionId":"gdfs23s","billing":    {"addressLine1":"911 Fallen  Street","addressLine2":"1 2"},"shipping":{"addressLine1":"1523 Willow Tree LAne","addressLine2":"unit 15"}}}
```

I want to clean up the data, performing tasks such as removing extra white space, normalizing postal abbreviation, ie street to st, etc.

I've written a series of regular expression that successfully achieve the cleansing/normalization.

However what I am unsure of is how to do this efficiently AND elegantly apply these cleanse processes to an Object in JS /Node.js.  I will have scenarios where I want to cleanse request.billing.addressLine1,  request.shipping.addressLine1 with the same regex pattern

I could of course do something like:
    var addressCleaner= new RegExp("( str| street| strt)","g");
    myObj.request.billing.addressLine1.replace(addressCleaner, "st"); 
    myObj.request.shipping.addressLine1.replace(addressCleaner, "st");

But I dont feel this is very DRY and furthermore its not being done very "node"ishly.

Any suggestions or example approaches?  I would like to avoid using a package like Mongoose etc. to do this as the type of normalizing i'm doing does not just consist of making sure a string is a string ,etc.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use the 2nd param of JSON.parse to revive your data into a clean format. since that function touches every property and value, there's no need to specify deep paths and loops. you can use a switch() to fix the data selectively based on value or key...

Comment: @dandavis: He's already parsed the JSON and already has an object from it. Read the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I would suggest to have a hash with all normalizers, and seperately to have a list of properties,
which needs to be normalized. To have the idea here some code:

```
var Normalizers = {
    // -> function
    trim: function(str) { return str.trim(); },
    // -> array [RegExp, StringToReplace]
    street: [ /(str|street)/g, 'st']

    //...
};

var properties = {
    'request.billing.addressLine1': ['trim', 'street'],
    // ..
};

obj_normalize(myObj, properties, Normalizers);
```

---

The code for `obj_normalize/obj_getProprety/obj_setProperty` I moved to the [gist](https://gist.github.com/tenbits/7146008).

Comment: Thanks for the code example, it works great.  I like this solution, it is easy to extend the normalization and add to it.  I will end up setting this as its own service/middleware.  I must say though, I am not sure I fully understand all the code.  I am new to JS but I'll use mozilla JS docs to see if I work through it all.

Comment: Small lib or a middleware with these feature, would be really useful. If you create a github repo for it, i would eager help you. Please notify me on github - _same profile name_. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If your regex is applicable to every string found within the object you can simply recurse through the object and apply the regex to every string.

A general purpose object traversal function is very useful for something like this:

```
function object_traverse (name,obj,fn) {
    obj = fn(name,obj);
    if (obj instanceof Array) {
        for (var n=0;n<obj.length;n++) {
            obj[n] = object_traverse(n,obj[n],fn);
        }
    }
    else if (typeof obj != "string" && typeof obj != "number") {
        for (var n in obj) {
            obj[n] = object_traverse(n,obj[n],fn);
        }
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Now you can do this:

```
myObj = object_traverse('',myObj,function(name,obj){
    if (typeof obj == "string" && name.match(/address/i)) {
        obj = obj.replace(addressCleaner, "st");
    }
    return obj;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd have a model built from JSON files and serialize it as I see fit. This would avoid matching or searching for properties which couldn't possibly exist in the source. Some example:

```
function makeAddress(rawAddress) {
    return { street: rawAddress["str"] || 
                     rawAddress["street"] ||
                     rawAddress["strt"],
             . . . };
```

Being equipped with this function, say, then you have an array of "address" object, then converting them would be a matter of:

```
addresses.map(makeAddress);
```